# Angular UI Router child resolves

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a parent-child relationship in my UI router config with using different resolves and it doesn't seem to be working.  I want to have a common parent state with child states that control whether the state is in edit mode or new mode.  Depending on the mode, the resolve of the state is different.

What I have is essentially this:

```
    .state('main.details', {
        url: "/details",
        templateUrl: "modules/details.html",
        abstract: true
    })

    .state('main.details.new', {
        controller: "DetailsCtrl as detailsCtrl",
        resolve : {
            detail: ['$stateParams', 'NewService', function ($stateParams, NewService) {

                return NewService.getDetail($stateParams.detailId, true);
            }]
        }
    })

    .state('main.details.edit', {
        controller: "DetailsCtrl as detailsCtrl",
        resolve : {
            detail: ['$stateParams', 'EditService', function ($stateParams, EditService) {

                return EditService.getDetail($stateParams.detailId, true);
            }]
        }
    })
```

Doing it this way, I get this:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: detailProvider <- detail <- DetailsCtrl
```

Is there a way to have a parent state that just defines the URL and templateUrl and then have child states with varying resolves?

Comment: That error is indicating that DetailsCtrl doesn't exist.  Are you sure you registered that controller correctly with your app?

Comment: What does your NewService or EditService return? A promise or some result value?

Comment: Both return a promise, yes.

Answer (score 0):

One option to help with this would be to pull out the repeating resolve on the routes and put it into a factory that the controller can call on